# Unable to show listbox item

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm trying to apply a Item Style to my listbox and there's no error and it's not working so I've tried to get a working point to start from and I can't even print a "hello world", I'm really confused since I,ve worked with listbox before and it was working

Edit :

Xaml

```
<ListBox Width="200" Height="200"
         ItemsSource="{Binding OCsTest, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                            FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Main

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public ObservableCollection<string> OCsTest { get; set; }
   public MainWindow()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      OCsTest = new ObservableCollection<string> { "This", "is", "a", "test." };
   }
}
```

Comment: Posted code works fine. What issue you facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the order of the statements in the ctor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    OCsTest = new ObservableCollection<string> { "This", "is", "a", "test." };

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

It is strongly recommended that you move the observablecollection away from code behind into a proper ViewModel and use that as the Window's DataContext, though.

**Edit:**

Since you're using a `RelativeSource` binding to bind against a property of the Window itself (which is not a good practice, IMO). The problem is, since the Window does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, setting the property after calling `InitializeComponent()` does not update the UI.

Comment: Works fine without even reversing.

Comment: @HighCore, what does the order have to do with it?

Comment: @GarryVass do you know what `InitializeComponent()` does in WPF?

Comment: @GarryVass the `DataContext` does not come into play here. The OP is using a `RelativeSource` binding to bind against a property of the `Window` itself (which is not a good practice, IMO). The problem is, since the Window does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, setting the property after calling `InitializeComponent()` does not update the UI.

Comment: @HighCore - Have you tried without reversing? Order doesn't matter here in this case.

Comment: @HighCore, nice explanation.  Can you upgrade your answer by pasting in the comment?

Comment: I gave +1 for amending your answer with a lucid explanation; I suppose the dv had to do with the ordering idea.  I have not checked the code personally.

Comment: I know I should use MVVM, but this was testing on another, similar, control, to not the current work, but thank

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise a property change on `OCsTest`. You did set the `OCsTest` but you never raised the new value back to the `UI` thus it is not going to show up.

Plus you are not doing `MVVM` pattern. What is the benefit here using the bindings? Why don't you just use set the `ItemssSource` property of the `ListBox` directly to the `OCsTest`.